# How can I download these slides created in Javascript?

Tags: web, web-application

How are  slides similar to https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide created? by some Javascript frameworks/libraries?

How can I download these slides (https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide) and convert them into pdf files? (I am on Ubuntu)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print them directly to PDF from Chrome. It's almost perfect for me

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYPPL.png)